# What does "pali" mean in this context?

Tags: littérature

I'm aware that pâli means "paled", as in to have grown pale. However, in this poem by Proust the author writes that Chopin is "plus beau d’etre pali": http://www.alalettre.com/proust-poemes-chopin.php

Does pali mean the same thing as pâli here? If so, why is the accent missing? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closer, you'll notice that all accents are missing in that transcription, not just the one on *pâli*.

That should be then:

> Tu t'exaltes encore, plus beau d'être pâli
>   Du soleil inondant ta chambre de malade

and *pâli* means *paled* (by the sun).